# Polymer: want to open new html page on tapping of a tag or button

Tags: polymer, nativeapplication

I developing native mobile app using Polymer and need basic help.

I want new .html page will be open on click `<a>` tag or button in Polymer

Answer (score 2):

Example with both button and link:

http://jsbin.com/rayasoquca/edit?html,output

Link:

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">Stackoverflow</a>
```

Button:

```
<button on-click="openStack">Stackoverflow</paper-button>
```

click event handler:

```
openstack: function() {
  window.open('https://stackoverflow.com', '_blank');
  // or: location.href='https://stackoverflow.com';
}
```